# Why are there multiple names of the same person?

Tags: name

In hindu texts, the same person typically has multiple names.

The Vishnu Sahastranamam is the biggest example. 
Shiva has many names such as Rudra, Neelkanth, Manjunath, etc.
Mahadevi has many names including Parvati, Durga, Kaali, etc.

Why are there so many names of the same person? Is it specific to the gods/Kings/revered people, or do most people in the texts have multiple names?

**Aside**: Please add proper tags to this question :)

Comment: This is usually to do with the fact, that names of deity or heroes weren't just their birth or original names, but more than that. For e.g. Kr̥ṣṇa is also known as Vasudeva, as his father was named so. So, other than common name, he also follows his father's name, his mother's name Devakīnandana. Then you have various titles associated with the deity's qualities, their mount, their ritual significances, from mythical stories associated to them, their other names from other incarnations and forms, their titles etc. And you have furthermore names from differing langs, texts and traditions.

Comment: In the case of mortal heroes like Arjuna, he is a prince, most of his other names such as Dhananjaya too are based either on his qualities or his titles. Pārtha is an affectionate name which Kr̥ṣṇa (who is both his cousin brother, friend as well his brother-in-law) uses for him, and so on.